# Is there a way to disable Android ListView animation?

Tags: android, listview

When we drag a `ListView` to the end or to the top, we can always drag it a little further and it will show a blank background, then when we release it the `ListView` will bounce back. It's a default animation effect of `ListView`.

I would like to disable this animation effect.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This may work.  Create a new class that contains the following.

```
import android.view.View;

public class OverScrollDisabler
{
    public static void disableOverScroll(View view)
    {
        view.setOverScrollMode(View.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);
    }
}
```

Then within your code,

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 9)
{
    OverScrollDisabler.disableOverScroll(myView);
}
```

More details here: http://jasonfry.co.uk/?id=30

Answer (score 10):

In your xml add the attribute

```
android:overScrollMode="never"
```

Answer (score 3):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#setOverScrollMode(int)

Comment: Thanks for the link. But my App is based on Android 1.6. Do you know if there is a solution under 1.6?

Answer (score 2):

For older versions api < 9 consider:

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)
{
    int action = ev.getAction();


    if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
        ev.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL);
        super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
        return true;
    }       

    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
}
```