# How to turn off animation of android listview?

Tags: android, scroll, android-listview

In android >2.2 (I'm developing an application on android 3.0). When you scroll a listview till the end, there's an animation/effect (a light flashes). Could I turn it off?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to disable Android ListView animation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5778820/is-there-a-way-to-disable-android-listview-animation)