# How do I disable the overscroll and the bounce in an android listview?

Tags: android, listview, scroll

The behaviour of my listview on 2 devices is that either it turns yellow/orange when I overscroll it, or that it can be overscrolled and then snaps back. The latter behaviour is bad because it shows the background beneath it which I want to prevent.

I tried:

```
listview.setOverScrollMode(ListView.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);
```

and it doesn't show the background anymore but now there is a very annoying bounce effect. Is it possible to both disable the bounce and the overscrolling and make it so the scrolling just ends without any effect when it reaches the end ?

PS: I am using android 2.3 on both devices.

Comment: Check this answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5778820/is-there-a-way-to-disable-android-listview-animation

Comment: Check this answer. Works perfectly.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7777803/listview-top-highlight-on-scrolling/17569996#17569996

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution to the annoying bounce effect? I am seeing it in my listviews as well.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I solved this, hopefully it will help those searching.  The key is to attach an OnScrollListener to the list, keep track of when a fling gesture is being processed, and when the end of the list has been reached.  Then, while the fling is still going on, keep on resetting the position to the end if the system tries to move it.

```
private ListView mListView;
private ListAdapter mAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_list);

    mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, getList(25));
    mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    mListView.setOverScrollMode(View.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD || Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD_MR1){
        mListView.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener(){
            private boolean flinging = false;
            private boolean reachedEnd = false;

            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
                flinging = (scrollState == AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_FLING);
                reachedEnd = false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
                if(reachedEnd && flinging && (firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount < totalItemCount)){
                    mListView.setSelection(mAdapter.getCount() - 1);
                }else if(firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount == totalItemCount){
                    reachedEnd = true;
                }else{
                    reachedEnd = false;
                }

            }

        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a mylistview class, extending listview, and you could override the overScrollBy method and set maxOverScrollY to zero